# Content-Disposition to set the file name is ignored in IE6. Url from web.xml is diplayed as file name

Tags: java, internet-explorer, servlets

This is the code snippet I am trying to run. It is working fine locally, but if I try to run it in a unix server, the name of the down loaded file is displayed as the url mapped to the servlet in the `web.xml` instead of `Report.xls`. Please help me…

```
response.reset();
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=Report.xls;");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known IE issue. It indeed completely ignores the filename in the `Content-Disposition` header and uses the last part of the URL pathinfo as default filename in the *Save As* dialogue. You should add the filename of the download file as part of the pathinfo. E.g http://example.com/context/reportservlet/report.xls where the servlet is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/reportservlet/*` (note the trailing `/*`) in `web.xml`.

If you want to get the specified filename in the servlet so that you can do one and other more dynamically, then you can use [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) for this.

```
String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
// Substring gets rid of leading `/`.
```

#### See also:

- [Basic fileservlet example](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq :)

Comment: For the record: I recall that IE6 *does* use the filename parameter; so there's probably something else that's causing this. Maybe the trailing semicolon?